# how to update multiple rows from subquery?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm now using `DB2` and try to update multiple rows, but below query returns `SQL0811N`, that says

*The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row".*

I'm looking for the query which can update multiple rows by each values selected by sub-query.

```sql
update
    table_004
set
    status = 99,
    bar_date = (
        select
            max(foo_date) as bar_date
        from
            table_001 t1
            inner join
                table_002 t2
            on  t1.keyA = t2.keyA
            inner join
                table_003 t3
            on  t2.keyA = t3.keyA
            inner join
                table_004 t4
            on  t4.keyB = t3.keyB
        where
            t1.id in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        group by
            t1.id,
            t4.keyB
    )
```

Comment: The error and its cause is plain to see: the subquery is returning more than one row.  And you are in the best position to fix the logic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can get values what I want to update by the subquery, but is it impossible to update multiple rows by multiple results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table 004 is not necessary into the subsellect. Try this:

```
update table_004 t4
set (t4.status, t4.bar_date) =
(
    select  99,  max(foo_date)
    from table_001 t1
    inner join table_002 t2 on  t1.keyA = t2.keyA
    inner join table_003 t3 on  t2.keyA = t3.keyA
    where t1.id in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and t4.keyB = t3.keyB
    group by t1.id
)
where exists
(
    select *
    from table_001 t1
    inner join table_002 t2 on  t1.keyA = t2.keyA
    inner join table_003 t3 on  t2.keyA = t3.keyA
    where t1.id in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and t4.keyB = t3.keyB
)
```

Comment: @Esperanto57 This query is way clearer than mine and executed exactly what I expected. Thank you for the answer and I marked this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have added

- a conditions to compare id between the table which I want to update and the table which is used in subquery
- `where` clause to `update` statement

and query is been executed exactly what I want. Hooray!

edited SQL:

```sql
update
    table_004 t0
set
    status = 99,
    bar_date = (
        select
            max(foo_date) AS bar_date
        from
            table_001 t1
            inner join
                table_002 t2
            on  t1.keyA = t2.keyA
            inner join
                table_003 t3
            on  t2.keyA = t3.keyA
            inner join
                table_004 t4
            on  t4.keyB = t3.keyB
        where
            t1.id in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            and
            t0.keyB = t4.keyB -- added
        group by
            t1.id,
            t4.keyB
    )
    where t0.keyB in (100,101,102,103) -- added
```